# Pure Data: use library on windows

Tags: windows, libraries, puredata

I am trying to send an UDP message from Pure Data on Windows, but I am unable to install or use libraries.

I put the library files in "C:/Program/common files/Pd", but Pd doesn't recognize when I type "import libraryName" in a object and leaves it undetermined.

Does someone know how to use Pure Data libraries on Windows ?

Edit : The problem is not the syntax, you can find it in google. In fact, I found that you need to download a specific .dll to use libraries on windows.

But thanks to Umläute, I simply used the built in functions and now it works.

Comment: You might want to add information on which Pd and Windows versions.

Comment: [import] is itself an external. Does this object instantiate?

Comment: also, `[import]` has been deprecated in favour of `[declare]`

Comment: what is *you need to download a specific dll to use libraries on windows* supposed to mean? you obviously need the `library.dll`, but *nothing* more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do `udp` communication, then you don't need any externals:

- `[netsend -u]` will send `FUDI` messages over UDP
- `[netsend -u -b]` will send *any* message over UDP (the `-b` is for *binary*, so you just pass it the raw list of bytes you want to transmit)
- `[oscformat]` will create an OSC-message (as raw bytes) from a Pd-message

You will need *Pd>=0.46* for this (which you want anyhow)

Comment: So eventually there is no library issue at all, because there is none needed. I deleted my answer and will fix the question accordingly.

Comment: @MaxN well yes and no; just because the problem at hand could be solved without libraries, doesn't mean that it's not interesting on it's own to be able to load libraries. i would recommend to undelete your answer.

Comment: Two unrelated issues in one question is not really stackoverflow style conform. I am quite confident there will be a question about library loading coming up soon.